# Getting error "Exception has been thrown by task scheduler" while opening Visual Studio in Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2013

After Automatic updates installation of windows 7 encountered the error

> Exception has been thrown by task scheduler

while opening the Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to install this update if we are getting the error "Exception has been thrown by the task scheduler".
This is because of the D3DCOMPILER_47.dll is missing.

Link to download the update :

http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/updt/2017/05/windows6.1-kb4019990-x64_35cc310e81ef23439ba0ec1f11d7b71dd34adfe5.msu